# Remove specific class from group of elements without jquery

Tags: javascript

I have multiple `span` elements, I try to remove the class `activeLang`.
How can I do this?

```
<div class="header_content_lang">
    <span class="langNav">
        ...
    </span>
    <span class="langNav">
        ...
    </span>
    <span class="langNav activeLang">
        ...
    </span>
</div>
```

I tried it like this, just like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22270709/4684797):

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".activeLang");

[].forEach.call(x, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove(".activeLang");

});

console.log(x[0]);
console.log(x[1]);
console.log(x[2]);
```

But output is "undefined" for all logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.` from the classname

```
el.classList.remove("activeLang");
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("activeLang");
  console.log(x[0]); //will print the object
  [].forEach.call(x, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("activeLang");
  });
  console.log(x[0]); //will no longer print the object
};
```

```html
<div class="header_content_lang">
  <span class="langNav">
        ...
    </span>
  <span class="langNav">
        ...
    </span>
  <span class="langNav activeLang">
        ...
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another off topic question, i don't want to create an extra question for this, can someone tell me how I can add a class to one element?
`x[2].className = "MyClass";` does not work

Comment: @EdwardBlack use add method of classlist https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods

Answer (score 6):

On modern, up-to-date browsers you can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) on the `HTMLCollection` (which inherits from `NodeList`) returned by `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".activeLang").forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.remove("activeLang");
});
```

On old browsers, you need to polyfill it, which you can do like this:

```
if (!NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach
    });
}
```

You may also need a polyfill for [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

On truly obsolete browsers (IE8), you'd have to polyfill [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (and `classList`) first.

Or use any of the "array-like" looping mechanism described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of typos in your code: you're putting a dot in the name of the class `activeLang` and it's not necessary (in `getElementsByClassName` and `remove`).

Supposing you fixed the typo, you'd still get undefined in your `console.log`. The reason is due to two things:

1. The length of the list is, at most, one (that would explain why x[1] and x[2] are `undefined`).
2. `getElementsByClassName` returns a live `HTMLCollection` of found elements so, even though the list has one element before performing the remove of the class, the length will be zero when you actually remove it (therefore x[0] is `undefined` too).

Hope this clarifies things.