# How to append a class if element contains certain CSS property

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add 'onclick' functionality to certain elements. These elements are perfectly targeted with this CSS, setting pointer-events to 'auto':

```
.custom-collections .o_slideshow .end-group {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.custom-collections > .o_slideshow:first-child,
.custom-collections > .o_slideshow .o_slide[data-id="home_slide"],
.custom-collections > .o_slideshow:last-child {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

My javascript currently enables the elements to be **dragged** (on drag) and **previewed** (on long touch). Ultimately, I need it only to be **previewed**.

In the javascript, I include this, to disable drag functionality if 'defaultSlide' is one of the classes:

```
            if (event.target.classList.contains('defaultSlide')) {
                // If the slide contains 'defaultSlide', it shouldn't be draggable.
                return;
            }
```

How should I append the class `defaultSlide` to the elements? 
Alternatively, what else could I do, instead of an `if class` method, to have my drag-script return immediately?

*Normally, I would add the class 'defaultSlide' to these elements in javascript when the elements are first created, but that requires a lot of code in my context of bad legacy code*

Comment: Did you try hasClass method with jQuery?

Comment: How do hasClass differ from event.target.classList.contains?

Comment: Keep in mind that import the whole library just to use a single function might not be a good aproach.

Comment: Is there any problem to run over all this elements and add the `defaultSlide` class? Alternatively, have you tried to add some class to their parent element?

Comment: Short answer; yes, there's problems. In javascript, I cannot only target the ones I want to target. The CSS _does_ already target just the right ones, but those CSS selectors will only allow me to change properties, like I do with `pointer-events` - not append a class, that my javascript can point at in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that CSS perfectly targets the elements, you have at least two options:

1. [`Element#matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) checks to see if the element you call it on matches the CSS selector you provide. So you could use `Element#matches` instead of your class check when you get the event, to see if the element matches those selectors:

   ```
   var selectors = '.custom-collections .o_slideshow .end-group, ' +
                   '.custom-collections > .o_slideshow:first-child, ' +
                   '.custom-collections > .o_slideshow .o_slide[data-id="home_slide"], ' +
                   '.custom-collections > .o_slideshow:last-child';
   if (event.target.matches(selectors)) {
       // return;
   }
   ```
2. [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a collection of elements that match the CSS selector you provide. So on page load, you could use `querySelectorAll` to get all elements matching those selectors and add the class to them:

   ```
   var selectors = '.custom-collections .o_slideshow .end-group, ' +
                   '.custom-collections > .o_slideshow:first-child, ' +
                   '.custom-collections > .o_slideshow .o_slide[data-id="home_slide"], ' +
                   '.custom-collections > .o_slideshow:last-child';
   document.querySelectorAll(selectors).forEach(function(e) {
       e.classList.add("defaultSlide");
   });
   ```

   ...and then use your existing code that checks for the class when you get the event.

---

Side note: The object returned by `querySelectorAll` only recently got the `forEach` method used above; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46550043/157247) for details and workaround for slightly out-of-date browsers.

Comment: So close! The selector works for the last three bits, but not the `.custom-collections .o_slideshow .end-group` one. Maybe I need something else than `, +` on the first line of the selectors?

Comment: @KarlKristiansen: No, that code is correct. If there are elements that match `.custom-collections .o_slideshow .end-group`, they'll be matched. If you're not seeing that, it suggests that selector is incorrect.