# How to change React component from outside?

Tags: reactjs

The React component, which can be considered as third-party component, looks as following:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { extractCommonClassNames } from '../../utils';

export const Tag = (props: React.ElementConfig): React$Node =>{
    const{
        classNames,
        props:
        {
            children,
            className,
            ...restProps
        },
    } = extractCommonClassNames(props);

    const combinedClassNames = classnames(
        'tag',
        className,
        ...classNames,
    );

    return (
        <span
          className={combinedClassNames}
          {...restProps}
        >
          {children}
          <i className="sbicon-times txt-gray" />
        </span>
    );
};
```

The component where I use the component above looks as following:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as L from '@korus/leda';
import type { KendoEvent } from '../../../types/general';

type Props = {
  visible: boolean
};

type State = {
  dropDownSelectData: Array<string>,
  dropDownSelectFilter: string
}

export class ApplicationSearch extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dropDownSelectData: ['Имя', 'Фамилия', 'Машина'],
      dropDownSelectFilter: '',
    };
    this.onDropDownSelectFilterChange = this.onDropDownSelectFilterChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.querySelector('.sbicon-times.txt-gray').classList.remove('txt-gray');
  }

  onDropDownSelectFilterChange(event: KendoEvent) {
    const data = this.state.dropDownSelectData;
    const filter = event.filter.value;
    this.setState({
      dropDownSelectData: this.filterDropDownSelectData(data, filter),
      dropDownSelectFilter: filter,
    });
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  filterDropDownSelectData(data, filter) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
    return data.filter(element => element.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      visible,
    } = this.props;

    const {
      dropDownSelectData,
      dropDownSelectFilter,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          visible && (
            <React.Fragment>
              <L.Block search active inner>
                <L.Block inner>
                  <L.Block tags>
                    <L.Tag>
                      option 1
                    </L.Tag>
                    <L.Tag>
                      option 2
                    </L.Tag>
                    <L.Tag>
                      ...
                    </L.Tag>
                  </L.Block>
                </L.Block>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to remove `"txt-gray"` from the component from outside and if so, how?

Comment: Please define `outside`.

Comment: I mean to write something from code where I use that component that will remove "txt-gray". The component itself should stay as black-box.

Comment: You can pass it as a prop from parent component and in parent, decide whether to pass this prop or not.

Comment: But, I don't want to change the component's code.

Comment: via props maybe?

Comment: *I don't want to change the component's code* - is there a reason for this? This approach is incorrect in React.

Comment: The reason is it's not my library with that component.

Comment: That's a valid reason. Consider updating the post with the mention that this is *third-party* component, this changes the context of the question.

Comment: If you want to hide instead of remove, a css class of  `.txt-gray { display:none; }` would do the job.

Comment: @tesicg Do you want to remove the class or only the css styling associated with that class? I image it only changes the color of the icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the class from where you're using the Tag component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.querySelector('.sbicon-times.txt-gray').classList.remove('txt-gray')
}
```

Or more specific:

```
.querySelector('span i.sbicon-times.txt-gray')
```

As per your comment,

> I have multiple components with "txt-gray", but when I use your code, "txt-gray" has been removed from first component only. How to remove it from all components?

I will suggest you to use the code to remove the class in the parent component of using the Tag component. And also use [querySelectorAll as in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270664/how-to-remove-a-class-from-elements-in-pure-javascript).

Comment: Beware, this will remove the txt-grey class from all the Tag components (and from any other component that has both sbicon-times and txt-grey css classes)

Comment: @estus There's no anyway to change without touching the component. So, the selector should choose specific element to remove class from it.

Comment: There are ways but they aren't pretty. I guess I'll post an answer for completeness.

Comment: I have multiple components with "txt-gray", but when I use your code, "txt-gray" has been removed from first component only. How to remove it from all components?

Comment: `.querySelector('.txt-gray')`??

Comment: @tesicg just use `.querySelectorAll` with same arguments, then loop on the return value and remove the class using `item.classList.remove('txt-gray')`

Comment: This one: document.querySelectorAll('span i.sbicon-times.txt-gray'); doesn't work at all, which means all is gray.

Comment: @tesicg `for (let item of document.querySelectorAll('span i.sbicon-times.txt-gray')) item.classList.remove('txt-gray')` should actually work

Answer (score 1):

## Refactoring

A clean way is to modify the component to allow it to conditionally add `txt-gray` through a prop:

```
<i className={classnames('sbicon-times', { 'txt-gray': props.gray })} />
```

If the component cannot be modified because it belongs to third-party library, this involves forking a library or replacing third-party component with its modified copy.

## Direct DOM access with `findDOMNode`

A workaround is to access DOM directly in parent component:

```
class TagWithoutGray extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).querySelector('i.sbicon-times.txt-gray')
    .classList.remove('txt-gray');
  }

  // unnecessary for this particular component
  componentDidUpdate = componentDidMount; 

  render() {
    return <Tag {...this.props}/>;
  }
}
```

The use of `findDOMNode` is generally discouraged because direct DOM access is not idiomatic to React, it has performance issues and isn't compatible with server-side rendering.

## Component patching with `cloneElement`

Another workaround is to patch a component. Since `Tag` is function component, it can be called directly to access and modify its children:

```
const TagWithoutGray = props => {
  const span = Tag(props);
  const spanChildren = [...span.props.children];
  const i = spanChildren.pop();

  return React.cloneElement(span, {
    ...props,
    children: [
      ...spanChildren,
      React.cloneElement(i, {
        ...i.props,
        className: i.props.className.replace('txt-gray', '')
      })
    ]
  });
}
```

This is considered a hack because wrapper component should be aware of patched component implementation, it may break if the implementation changes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible

The only way is to change your Tag component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { extractCommonClassNames } from '../../utils';

export const Tag = (props: React.ElementConfig): React$Node =>{
    const{
        classNames,
        props:
        {
            children,
            className,
            ...restProps
        },
    } = extractCommonClassNames(props);

    const combinedClassNames = classnames(
        'tag',
        className,
        ...classNames,
    );

    const grayClass = this.props.disableGray ? 'sbicon-times' : 'sbicon-times txt-gray';

    return (
        <span
          className={combinedClassNames}
          {...restProps}
        >
          {children}
          <i className={grayClass} />
        </span>
    );
};
```

Now, if you pass `disableGray={true}` it will suppress the gray class, otherwise of you pass false or avoid passing that prop at all it will use the gray class. It is a small change in the component, but it allows you not to change all the points in your code where you use this component (and you are happy with grey text)