# How to get 'ref' of wrapped element in react < 16?

Tags: reactjs, ref

My form fields wrapped by a react component individually. This react component comes from 3rd party module. My challenge is to set 'ref' and get that 'ref' outside of that component so I can call `.focus` on it.

Note: I don't have access to modify code of 3rd party module.

I can't use .createRef and .forwardRef as don't have access to code and importantly not using React 16+

`<WrapperComponent/>` This component has input field on which I need to set focus from outside.

**Structure is like below:**

```
    MyComponent: // Where I want to access the ref

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <WrapperComponent id={id} />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

**Wrapper Component (This is a 3rd party component which has input fields inside. May be structure is like below):**

```
    render() {
        return (<input type="text" id={id} />);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean way is to fork third-party component and make it expose a ref.

One workaround is to extend third-party component:

```
class FirstParty extends ThirdParty {
  inputRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    const inputReactEl = super.render();
    return React.cloneElement(inputReactEl, { ref: this.inputRef });
  }
}
```

Another workaround is to wrap it:

```
class FirstParty extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.inputDomEl = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
  }

  render() {
    return <ThirdParty {...this.props}/>;
  }
}
```

In case React 15 is in use, `createRef` refs can be changed to legacy refs.

Comment: thank you. First one is good workaround but that may not work if the input field is wrapped by any other element like <div>.

Second one is incomplete I guess.

Comment: You need to be aware of parent render. In case there's a div, you need to dig deeper inside element hierarchy, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316157/how-to-change-react-component-from-outside/53317226#53317226. The same applies to second option, use querySelector if needed.

Comment: "A clean way is to fork third-party component and make it expose a ref." lastly I did this one as this was the best, clean approach. Owner of that third party component accepted my PR and merged into :). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a ref to your own `div` and write some code to find the node you need among its children.

Since you have an `id` you can just `window.document.getElementById(id)` to access that node.