# How to remove one class from many elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, class

I want to remove class name "active" from every element that have it  in P1 and P2 on button click.I have added active class in javascript by `classList.add()`

```
let P1 = document.getElementsByClassName("P1")
let P2 = document.getElementsByClassName("P2")
```

In my HTML file I have

```
        <div id="p1Highlight">
            <div class="P1" id="m0">0</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m1">1</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m2">2</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m3">3</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m4">4</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m5">5</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m6">6</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m7">7</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m8">8</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m9">9</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m10">10</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m11">11</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m12">12</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m13">13</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m14">14</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m15">15</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m16">16</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m17">17</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m18">18</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m19">19</div>
            <div class="P1" id="m20">20</div>
        </div>
        <p>Player 2 Score</p>
        <div id="p2Highlight">
            <div class="P2" id="a1">1</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a2">2</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a3">3</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a4">4</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a5">5</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a6">6</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a7">7</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a8">8</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a9">9</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a10">10</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a11">11</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a12">12</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a13">13</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a14">14</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a15">15</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a16">16</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a17">17</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a18">18</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a19">19</div>
            <div class="P2" id="a20">20</div>
        </div>
```

I am giving them the class of "active" like this

```
function p1HighlightDisp(){

    if(player1Score < 20){
        player1Highlight = document.getElementById(`m${player1Score}`)

        player1Highlight.classList.add("active");
    }

}

function p2HighlightDisp() {

    if (player2Score < 20) {
        player2Highlight = document.getElementById(`a${player2Score}`)

        player2Highlight.classList.add("active");
    }

}
```

Know I want to remove class name of active from every element that has it on button click.How would I do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a class from elements in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270664/how-to-remove-a-class-from-elements-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: the answers provided below + answers in the suggested duplicate, the recommended way is to use `classList` with `replace` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target the elements with the `active` class and remove the class from the `classList` of each element.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  const active = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
  active.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
}
```

```css
.active { color: red; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<button>Remove active class</button>
<div id="p1Highlight">
  <div class="P1" id="m0">0</div>
  <div class="P1" id="m1">1</div>
  <div class="P1 active" id="m2">2</div>
  <div class="P1" id="m3">3</div>
  <div class="P1 active" id="m4">4</div>
  <div class="P1" id="m5">5</div>
</div>
<div id="p2Highlight">
  <div class="P2 active" id="a1">1</div>
  <div class="P2" id="a2">2</div>
  <div class="P2" id="a3">3</div>
  <div class="P2" id="a4">4</div>
  <div class="P2 active" id="a5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.It solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.remove("active")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work even after you fix the typos. `document.getElementsByClassName` [Warning: This is a live HTMLCollection. Changes in the DOM will reflect in the array as the changes occur. If an element selected by this array no longer qualifies for the selector, it will automatically be removed. Be aware of this for iteration purposes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Try adding a quick snippet showing it work. It doesn't work because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a live HTMLCollection. Check out the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `forEach`

```js
const isActive = document.querySelectorAll('.active');

isActive.forEach((element) => {
  // first check if active class exist or any element in your DOM have active class then remove it.
  if (element) {
    element.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('active');` is incorrect. You should be targeting the _class_.

Comment: thanks for letting me know I changed it to `.active`